# SFTP In Go Error: User does not have appropriate read permission

Tags: go, sftp

I am trying to upload a product feed to a Google Merchant SFTP account. I am able to upload a file manually through the command prompt but encounter the following error when trying to do it through Go.

**Error**: `sftp: "User does not have appropriate read permission." (SSH_FX_PERMISSION_DENIED)`

I am using the `github.com/pkg/sftp` package, following the example in https://godoc.org/github.com/pkg/sftp#Client.Open. I suspect that the `Create`/`Write` pattern here ends up being different from a simple `put` from command line.

**Code**

```
func (g *GoogleExporter) ExportToSFTP(file []byte) error {

// Creating an SSH connection
sshConfig := &ssh.ClientConfig{
    User: g.Creds.AccessData.SFTPUser,
    Auth: []ssh.AuthMethod{
        ssh.Password(g.Creds.AccessData.SFTPPassword),
    },
}

hostPort := fmt.Sprintf("%s:%d", SFTPHostName, SFTPHostPort)
connection, err := ssh.Dial("tcp", hostPort, sshConfig)
if err != nil {
    return err
}

fmt.Println(">> SSH Connection Created!")

// Creating an SFPT connection over SSH
sftp, err := sftp.NewClient(connection)
if err != nil {
    return err
}
defer sftp.Close()

fmt.Println(">> SFTP Client Created!")

// Uploading the file
remoteFileName := "products.xml" // TODO: Make this name configurable
remoteFile, err := sftp.Create(remoteFileName)
if err != nil {
    return err
}
fmt.Println(">> SFTP File Created!")
if _, err := remoteFile.Write(file); err != nil {
    return err
}

fmt.Println("Successfully uploaded product feed to SFTP, file:%s user:%s", remoteFileName, g.Creds.AccessData.SFTPUser)
util.Log("Successfully uploaded product feed to SFTP, file:%s user:%s", remoteFileName, g.Creds.AccessData.SFTPUser)

// Confirming if the file is there
if _, err := sftp.Lstat(remoteFileName); err != nil {
    return err
}

return nil
}
```

The error is cause by this line:

```
remoteFile, err := sftp.Create(remoteFileName)
```

Comment: You didn't set the current working directory when you create the file. `sftp.Create("/your/working/path/products.xml")`. Maybe at the moment of connect, your user doesn't have some privileges with the default directory path.

Comment: I tried doing a simple put from the command line and it uploaded the file with flags as `--w--w--w-`. When I look at the docs for `sftp.Create` creates a file with `0666`, which is what is causing it. I need to be able to create a file with write only permissions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am answering my own question to help anyone else that is having this problem. I was able to find a solution.

The **Google Merchant SFTP** account only gives you write only access. However, according to the docs, when using the `sftp.Create(..)` function, it creates a file with the flags as `0666`, which does not agree with the permissions set on your user.

To mimic the behavior of `sftp.Create(..)` with write only permissions, you can use the more general `sftp.OpenFile(..)` function.

```
remoteFile, err := sftp.OpenFile(fileName, os.O_WRONLY|os.O_CREATE|os.O_TRUNC)
```

The flags `os.O_WRONLY|os.O_CREATE|os.O_TRUNC` will mimic the behavior of `Create()` i.e. create a file it doesn't exist and truncate the file if it does.